# Video autoplay not working on some Safari browsers

Tags: html, css, mobile-safari, video.js

I have videos on my site that I autoplay using the VideoJS library. The videos are played as muted. The videos autoplay fine on the Safari browser with my iPhone, but do not work on some of my friends' phones (same phone and iOS version as me).

Sorry I don't have a lot of information as I cannot replicate the issue on my device. One clue I have is that I see a big play button on the problematic browsers (first image). I used CSS to style the play button differently (second image).

Any leads would be amazing. Thank you!

Here are my video tag and VideoJS options:

html:

```
<video
  playsinline
  muted
>
```

VideoJS Options:

```
{
  autoplay: true,
  controls: false,
  loop: true,
  muted: true,
  preload: 'auto',
};
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: On IOS devices safari block the autoplay by default

Comment: Autoplay on Safari should be OK if muted. Do the other phones have the same IOS versions and the same settings? Please put the relevant CSS and HTML into your question.

Comment: I did not check all the settings other than the iOS version (which is the same). Are there settings that could prevent videos from playing in the browser?

Comment: a [mcve] is more useful than a screenshot

Comment: @misterben the problem is that I cannot reproduce it. I am hoping someone will recognize the issue

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with this attr: autoplay, muted and playsinline. Example:

```
<video autoplay muted loop playsinline>
 <source src="video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Comment: Yes! Well auto-play is not in the tag since I have multiple videos and I don't want them all playing at once, but it is an option I pass to VideoJS.

Answer (score 0):

If you're seeing inconsistent behaviour across the same iPhone model and iOS/browser version, one likely explanation is that your friend's phones are on 'low-power mode' or 'low data mode' to preserve battery or bandwidth - these modes are known to disable video autoplay in Safari.

https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/709821

https://shaktisinghcheema.com/how-to-autoplay-video-on-mobile-devices-on-low-power-mode/